# Normalizing CSV columns in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, multidimensional-array

I've imported a dataset from CSV into Ruby as an array of arrays (each row is an array). I want to normalize each column from 0 to 1. Therefore, I have to find the max and min of each column. Is there an easy way to do this? Or do I have to parse each column value out of each row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array#transpose` to make the inner arrays be the columns, then use `Enumerable#min` and `#max` to get your values.

```
copy = csv_data.transpose
copy.each do |a| #do whatever you need here
  a.min
  a.max
end
```

or something like this

```
copy = csv_data.transpose
arr_min = copy.map(&:min) # returns an array of the min values
arr_max = copy.map(&:max) # returns an array of the max values
```

Comment: Great answer. Note that—if speed is an issue—you might be able to roughly halve the running time by (less elegantly) using a single `each` iteration to calculate both min and max. (But maybe not, given that min/max are implemented in C.)